# A reference pages for the latest version of c++

Tags: c++, c++11, reference-manual

For c++03, there are next reference pages :

- [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/)
- [IBM pages for c++](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.aix.doc/standlib/stl_vector.htm)
- MSDN c++ reference pages

I used [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/) as reference pages as a reference for c++ classes and functions (I am aware it is has errors, but is quite ok).

However, all these pages are for c++03.

Are there similar pages for c++11?

Comment: What compiler/version are you using? Microsoft probably has the docs for VS2010 in MSDN. I myself use *THE* standard for references (both INCITS+ISO+IEC-14882-2003 for the current standard and the FDIS for C++0x)

Comment: @David I am using g++ 4.6. The standard is ok, but I do not have the latest version (is it available?). Anyway, I find pages like cplusplus.com quite useful.

Comment: The C++ Tag has lots of reference links: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info

Comment: @VJo: what version do you have? n3290 (FDIS) is the *latest* I know of, and it was removed from the web (I was lucky enough to keep a copy until they approve and buy the official document), but there are almost no changes if there is any at all from [n3092](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf) (FCD) that should still be accessible.

Comment: Or more specifically the C++11 tag: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b11/info

Comment: @David I just got N3242 (as posted in c++11 info page, posted by Tux-D). *@Tux-D* Info pages for c++11 need an update. 350 CHF for a document is too much. Where is a 20$ version? Also, would be good to add a link posted by Emilion Garavaglia (see below)

Comment: @VJo: I bought an electronic copy of the current standard for $35, now it seems to be just $30, from the [ANSI webstore](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS/ISO/IEC%2014882-2003)

Comment: @David: That goes to C++03, not C++11.

Comment: @Nicol: Yes, it is the C++03 standard, as the C++0x has not yet been finalized (the standard procedures take time). It will be in the shop sometime after it gets the final approval, which should happen sometime this year. But before it actually becomes *the standard* you will not be able to buy it.

Comment: @David: C++11 has already been finalized (back in August) and [it is published](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ISO%2fIEC+14882%3a2011). It's _already_ the standard. That's what VJo was talking about when he said it was 350CHF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually refer to the latest 
[standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)

You can also check [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), but it is still incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

I often refer to the Bjarne Stroustrup's "[C++0x - the next ISO C++ standard](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html)" page.